# Cannot process row that is bigger than the IO size

Tags: impala

when i execute a sql in impala, i get this info:

Cannot process row that is bigger than the IO size (row_size=13.42 MB, null_indicators_size=0). To run this query, increase the IO size (--read_size option).

the explain is as follow:

```
06:SORT
|  order by: count(*) DESC
|  hosts=1 per-host-mem=unavailable
|  tuple-ids=7 row-size=24B cardinality=30000000
|
05:AGGREGATE [FINALIZE]
|  output: count(*)
|  group by: group_concat(host)
|  having: count(*) > 10
|  hosts=1 per-host-mem=unavailable
|  tuple-ids=6 row-size=24B cardinality=30000000
|
04:AGGREGATE [FINALIZE]
|  output: group_concat(host)
|  group by: gridsum_id
|  hosts=1 per-host-mem=unavailable
|  tuple-ids=4 row-size=31B cardinality=30000000
|
08:MERGING-EXCHANGE [UNPARTITIONED]
|  order by: g_id ASC, server_time ASC, session_order ASC
|  limit: 30000000
|  hosts=1 per-host-mem=unavailable
|  tuple-ids=2 row-size=46B cardinality=30000000
|
03:TOP-N [LIMIT=30000000]
|  order by: g_id ASC, server_time ASC, session_order ASC
|  hosts=1 per-host-mem=1.29GB
|  tuple-ids=2 row-size=46B cardinality=30000000
|
02:HASH JOIN [INNER JOIN, BROADCAST]
|  hash predicates: b.g_id = r.g_id
|  runtime filters: RF000 <- r.g_id
|  hosts=1 per-host-mem=2.00GB
|  tuple-ids=1,0 row-size=65B cardinality=unavailable
|
|--07:EXCHANGE [BROADCAST]
|  |  hosts=18 per-host-mem=0B
|  |  tuple-ids=0 row-size=46B cardinality=unavailable
|  |
|  00:SCAN HDFS [u_g.botao_route_all r, RANDOM]
|     partitions=1/1 files=18 size=213.24MB
|     predicates: r.host NOT IN ('-', '(lost)'), r.session_order > 0
|     table stats: unavailable
|     column stats: unavailable
|     hosts=18 per-host-mem=96.00MB
|     tuple-ids=0 row-size=46B cardinality=unavailable
|
01:SCAN HDFS [u_g.botao_id b, RANDOM]
   partitions=1/1 files=1 size=5.53MB
   predicates: b.profile_id = 2473
   runtime filters: RF000 -> b.g_id
   table stats: 160891 rows total
   column stats: unavailable
   hosts=1 per-host-mem=32.00MB
   tuple-ids=1 row-size=19B cardinality=16089
----------------
```

any one can help me, thanks a lots.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting this because of insufficient memory and limited spill IO buffer size.

```
Status BufferedTupleStream::NewBlockForWrite(int min_size, bool* got_block) {
    DCHECK(!closed_);
    if (min_size > block_mgr_->max_block_size()) {
      return Status(Substitute("Cannot process row that is bigger than the IO size "
            "(row_size=$0). To run this query, increase the io size (--read_size option).",
            PrettyPrinter::Print(min_size, TCounterType::BYTES)));
}
```

When spilling happens, Impala needs to write intermediate tuples row by row at a time, which requires the IO buffer being large enough to hold at least one row. In your case, this condition isn't met, resulting the aforementioned error.

You can either run the query with larger memory or adjust the block size by `--read_size` option, which is counter intuitive in such case though.